# Can I solder back together a single broken copper winding wire in an electric washing machine motor?

Tags: motor, ac, soldering, winding

Can I solder back together a single broken copper winding wire in an electric washing machine motor?  This is the motor: http://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/b5p11/Whirlpool-Washing-Machine-Drive-Motor/661600/675936?modelNumber=LSR7233EQ0&ss=a11b5d112106&mr=1 .  The culprit is in the topmost winding in this picture, closest to center top, near where a screw attaches the capacitor bracket to the motor housing. This is an induction motor, with no brushes, and the wire is in the stationary portion of the windings, not the inner spinning portion.  I have the motor out of the machine, which fills with water but only hums during agitate and spin cycles & won't drain.

I know how the break happened and can resolve that problem.  Years ago I upgraded the capacitor on this machine because I was using it off-grid with a generator and it needed just a little more help to start the demanding cycles. That upgrade worked fine, except that the bracket holding the capacitor was not quite large enough to secure both ears of the bracket under the screw on the motor housing.  I should have made another bracket that fit the new capacitor and pinned it down tight, but did not.

Now, in a different home with mains power (and after a couple years of use), the bracket slipped a little with the motion of the machine. The corner of the unpinned bracket made contact with one wire in the winding, which breached that wire. Here again, I should have re-installed the original capacitor, but did not, and it worked just fine.

I plan to replace the original working capacitor, which I still have, and whose diameter is slightly smaller allowing it to fit properly in the bracket and allowing both ears under the screw.The position of the broken wire makes soldering it back together in 20 minutes VERY tempting.  Worth trying?  I found plenty of recommendations to replace the motor, which is $161 plus shipping at repairclinic.com.  I found this hopeful note on http://books.google.com/books?id=lp3f5_JHrggC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=can+a+broken+armature+winding+be+soldered?&source=bl&ots=wGOwUearAB&sig=4jC4Utvw7mmKZj_iggZMsfvYKLg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zLdpVMHxKZDDiQLJwYDYBg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=can%20a%20broken%20armature%20winding%20be%20soldered%3F&f=false . This describes such a repair on a (much smaller, I assume) model train motor.  I'm a fairly competent solderer. Is this worth trying?

Comment: Be careful not to degrade (overheat) the adjacent turns, and insulate the repair well. And if that's the only fault, you should be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **big** issue here is safety- the motor has mains voltage on it. If you can get some clearance around the area and apply some insulation below and beside the break (I suggest Kapton/Polyimide tape) then you can scrape the insulation off the broken ends (may not be easy) and mend the break (without destroying the Kapton/Polyimide) possibly by adding a short jumper wire rather than trying to make a butt joint.

[image: http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-10338/3M-Specialty-Tapes/3M-5413-Polyimide-Film-Tape-1-2-x-36-yards]

You would then need more insulation over the top (I'd then slather it in epoxy after a quick test), and something like fish paper (rugged insulating material) to provide protection against any possible dangerous short to ground from chafing.

[image: http://www.vetco.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=9511&gclid=CLSlleiGgsICFQYFaQod1GgAbQ]

Personally, I'd give it a try to save $160 and shipping cost/time, but I can't judge your abilities so the safe suggestion is to go buy a new motor.

Comment: I'm not an unbiased judge of my abilities either, so with much ambition, I've ordered some 1" Kapton tape. A little more clarification though, please? I have cleaned the two ends of the broken wire (which aren't copper at all, but white metal, insulated by what I assume is a sprayed/baked on  polyamide film. It came off easily with a little piece of abrasive mesh. I will find an appropriate epoxy for slathering after, which, do share your choice?  As for fish paper (rugged insulating material), I'm unfamiliar with this product. Are there common effective substitutes & where/how do I apply it?

Comment: If the wire is aluminum you may have issues. It needs special flux and still sucks to solder. I know some motor mfrs have used aluminum to save weight and cost. They use ultrasonic soldering or plating or welding to connect to the ends, Other than fish paper- just some left-over blank (no copper) PCB material or anything else sturdy, doesn't burn & insulating.

Comment: It may well be aluminum. I can find some flux particular to aluminum and study up on proper technique for that. A suggestion came to me from a friend, to try a butt joint conductive silver epoxy instead of soldering, with the rest of the approach the same as you described. There's no (or minimal) apparent gap between the ends of the broken wire, and I can see how this might be possible. Your thoughts?

Comment: I'm not optimistic about that approach. Maybe you can peel enough back to use a small terminal strip or something like that (pressure).

Comment: Peel enough back, of what? The colored coating comes off easily with abrasive mesh...is that what I am "peeling" off? If so, how far back must I strip to apply this small terminal strip?I'll go look at terminal strips.

Comment: Maybe 3/4" / 20mm

Comment: Remember aluminum oxidizes in air, and the oxide has same tempco as bare Al. So you have to work pretty quickly after stripping off the tough oxide, it grows back...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can solder the wire in that motor to repair it. Years ago, I soldered a similar wire in a vacuum cleaner motor (it had broken away from the terminal at the end of the winding). Provided you don't make a short with another winding, and the repair is mechanically sound against the vibration of the motor, I think you'll be fine.